# Text Overlapping in child div containers inside a parent container when browser size width is shortened

Tags: html, css

Hello I am having trouble keeping two div containers from spilling their content beyond the boundaries of container and overlapping with each other when I shorten the website. I am using relative positioning for the parent div and absolute positioning for the child div.

I am wondering how I would fix this or if this method isn't possible a better solution could be shown.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Kelvin's Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div class = "ParentContainer">
        <div id = "Container1">
            <h1 class = "introText">Certifications</h1>
            <p class = "Text">AWS Certified Developer – Associate <br>
                              Amazon Web Services Training and Certification <br>
                              Expires: October 12, 2026 <br>        
                </p>
        </div>
        
        <div id = "Container2">
            <h1 class = "introText">Work Experience</h1>
            <p class = "Text">
                "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,,<br> 
                totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.<br>
                Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,<br> 
                 sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est,<br> 
                qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,<br> 
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.<br>
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam,<br> 
                nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui<br> 
                in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
            </p>

            <p class = "Text">
                "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,,<br> 
                totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.<br>
                Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,<br> 
                 sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est,<br> 
                qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,<br> 
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.<br>
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam,<br> 
                nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui<br> 
                in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
            </p>
        </div>


    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
    width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ParentContainer{
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px;
  border: 0px;
  height: 3000px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  position: relative;

}

.Text{
  color:aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#Container1{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 45%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#Container2{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 70%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Here is the link to Jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q0fzbL59/1/

Comment: What exactly do you want? can you show me design pictures? I don't know what 's the matter

Comment: If you resize the browser pane on the JS Fiddle, then you can observe that at smaller widths the layout breaks — one container becomes hidden behind the other and the bottom container starts to overflow its parent. I believe this is what the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Using absolute positioning for layout can lead to issues with content overlapping, especially when the content size changes (e.g. the viewport is resized) or the content length is dynamic.

I would suggest taking the time to get a basic understanding of both [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and using these for your site's layout.

Here's some updated CSS (using Flexbox) that solves your layout problems:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ParentContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.Text {
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#Container1, #Container2 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#Container1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#Container2 {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

The HTML can remain the same.

In the above code, `align-items: center;` centers the child divs on the cross axis and `justify-content: center;` centers them on the main axis.

If you would like to learn more about these layout methods, I recommend Wes Bos' video courses [What The Flexbox?](https://flexbox.io/) and [CSS Grid](https://cssgrid.io/). Both are free.

---

**Edit**: Here's an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1rhsxc4/).